# Serialize array/relation with attributes using ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I want to serialize relation using Active Model Serializers and I want to set some 'global' attributes (e.g. count) for this relation:

```
{
  users: {
    total: 12,
    page: 2,
    users: [{}, {}, {}, ...]
  }
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During your render call in the controller, you can pass in the meta attribute.

```
render @users, :each_serializer => UserSerializer, :meta => { :total => @users.count }
```

This will produce the following JSON:

```
{
  "users" : [...],
  "meta" : {
    "total" : 12
  }
}
```

You can rename the meta key name by passing in the `meta_key` option.

Comment: This is the correct json structure for JSONAPI specification, so this is what you should return to comply with the spec - a meta attribute

Comment: Note that this does have the same database impact as the answer from @Stanislav if you trigger this code as a result of calling a parent serialiser (you will fire a count query for every parent). On very large datasets (probably millions of rows) this will get slow. Just sayin' :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391167/ember-2-7-rails-5-jsonapi-active-model-serializers-counting-the-number-of-r

Answer (score 3):

You can define calculated properties in your serializer:

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :users_count
  has_many :users

  def users_count
    object.users.size
  end
end
```

Comment: This works and is ok for small datasets. Just be aware that this will fire a user count query for every Foo. So when hitting foo/index route, if you return 100 foo's: one query to get the Foos followed by 100 "select count(*) from users where foo.id=x"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391167/ember-2-7-rails-5-jsonapi-active-model-serializers-counting-the-number-of-r

Answer (score 0):

This will not make multiple DB calls for `count` as pointed out by
@rmcsharry

```
 { 
    data: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(
            @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer).as_json,
    count: @users.count 
 }
```